# Render heavy model / mesh on three.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, three.js

I know this is a well known question but I was not able to find a good answer.

**My usage**

I use three.js to display 3D models created through drone pictures ([here an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxfMC.jpg)).

**The problem**

I can't render heavy models (1M vertices, 2M faces) : Chrome or WebGl crashed.

**What I tried**

*I used Threejs.org examples for all my tests to be sure that it was not my code that didn't work. I made my test on a x64 Chrome with --max_old_space_size=6144 flag.*

- Import model in .dae with ColladaLoader --> 2.5Go of RAM is used and Chrome crash (displaying "not enough memory")
- Import model in .obj with OBJLoader + MTLLoader --> 2.8Go of RAM is used and WebGl crash
- I red many posts about Three.js and memory allocation but many of them speak about remove an object from the scene

**Possible solutions**

- I saw that .stl (binary) file are more compact, but as far as I know
  there is no texture with these files, so I can't use it
- Use BinaryLoader (which has GeometryBuffer output) but I need to convert .dae or .obj to binary files and I don't know how to do that
- Load my model in multiple parts to not load in one shot ? But I didn't saw any example or posts with that kind of treatment

**How to reproduce**

For the code, I use basics examples on Threejs.org. For models :

- If you want to try with .dae you can find on [this folder](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6uJpL0TeaHLcF9rSEYtU21ReFE) a working example (WorkingModel.dae / .jpg) and the model who don't work (BigModel.dae / .jpg)
- If you want to try with .obj you can find on [this folder](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6uJpL0TeaHLRmdnZ3h1YllGc0E) a working example (WorkingModel.dae / .jpg / .mtl) and the model who don't work (BigModel.dae / .jpg / .mtl)

Any ideas to load the big one ? 
Thanks !

**EDIT 1 :**

I tried to put a breakpoint in the SuccessCallback to see if the overload of RAM is during the load or after. I was not able to hit the breakpoint, so the overload of RAM is before the SuccessCallback.

Then I went step by step in the ColladaLoader to find what is using so much RAM. Here is the "callstack" :

- myCollada.load()
- ColladaLoader.parse()
- Geometry.parse()
- Mesh.parse()

  - Source.parse (hit 3 times) = +400mo in RAM
  - Vertices.parse = +0mo in RAM
  - Triangles.parse = +1500mo in RAM
  - this.geometry3js.computeVertexNormals() = RAM go over 2600Mo and chrome crash

Could I do any other tests to find the reason of this problem ? 
Thanks

Comment: Your model only has 2 million faces, yet it's using 2.5GB of memory? It sounds like some memory isn't getting released as it should. I've used models (custom format, not dae or obj) with up to 35 million faces, and while performance isn't great, it doesn't crash the browser. Also, I'm not keen on downloading random files, so could you please provide some information on them such as file size, and image resolution?

Comment: @TheJim01 thanks for your answer. My .dae size is 151MB, the .jpg size is 30MB (resolution : 16384*16384). I just uploaded my model [on sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/models/1dbb118af7eb4e098ea7efe9008fbdb4) this way you can see it and download it if you want to.

Comment: Obviously your model will render and perform well in WebGL. I recommend first putting some breakpoints in your code to see if the `ColladaLoader` ever reaches its done callback, and if the memory is already out of control at that point. Not reaching the breakpoint, or a memory glut points to a problem in the loader. Hitting the breakpoint with reasonable memory usage tells us the rest of the code is doing something bad with the loaded data.

Comment: Hi @TheJim01, I did what you suggested and I updated my post with the result. Thanks !

Comment: Try using `ColladaLoader2`. The original `ColladaLoader` uses the `Geometry` class, which--while easy to understand--creates a lot of JavaScript objects, and isn't as efficient as the alternative, `BufferGeometry`. It's no coincidence that `ColladaLoader2` uses `BufferGeometry`. :) _(As an aside, I don't know if their plans have changed, but last I heard, [`THREE.WebGL2Renderer` would ONLY support BufferGeometry](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9965).)_

Comment: Thanks @TheJim01 , it works with ColladaLoader2 (I also cut my texture width and heigth 16000px to 4000px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textures are waaaay to big, and besides, you don't need them because your model has baked vertex colors, which includes baked lighting. Your model therefore does not require UVs eiher.

Use `ColladaLoader2`, and this pattern. It should work.

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();

loader.load( 'BigModel.dae', function ( collada ) {

        var dae = collada.scene;

        dae.traverse( function( child ) {

            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

                child.geometry.removeAttribute( 'uv' ); // you don't need it

                child.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { // scene lights not required

                    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors // you have them, use them

                } );

                scene.add( child );
            }

        } );

} );
```

three.js r.86

Comment: Thanks @WestLangley, I tried with ColladaLoader2 and it works with a smaller texture. But as you said, I’m trying to use the color inside my model rather than my texture. Unfortunately, if I remove UVs I can’t see my model. I check in my mesh geometry and there is no colors. See : [my mesh geometry](http://imgur.com/a/eBt0E). Any advice ?

Comment: I previously invested considerable effort testing both of your models and and they were loaded having position, color, and uv attributes. Using vertex colors only, the demo was very responsive.